# how to use Collections.sort() in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android, may I get some help in understanding the following code snippet?

```
Collections.sort(songList, new Comparator<Song>(){

   public int compare(Song a, Song b){

     return a.getTitle().compareTo(b.getTitle());

   }

});
```

Comment: What *specifically* do you not understand?

Comment: Try googling `anonymous inner classes comparator`

Comment: You are making an anonymous inner class that implements the comparator interface, which forces you to implement the compare function. You need to do this so that the elements in songList can be compared to each other.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest reviewing the documentation?
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5

It's a particular case of the `new` syntax, `new Type<Generic>()`, only with a class body, `new Type<Generic>() { ... }`.

The code example you showed makes a mistake; it does not use the `@Override` annotation.